# ChartDirector sometimes draws crosses, refreshing sometimes shows data

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm using asp.net and ChartDirector Version 5.

I got a page, generating 3 Charts which is working locally perfect.

After uploading it to my webserver it draws f.e. chart 1 and 3, an leaves chart2 as a blue cross. When i refresh it draws something else, f.e. chart 2 and 3, but leaves chart 1 as a cross. Refreshing is randomly changing which ones are shown, but at least one chart, sometimes all.

All charts are using a session ID, to prevent wrong data to be shown

```
viewer1.ImageSessionId = "xyz" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

What are the reasons for that strange behaviour? What can I do?

I'd be glad for every advice :D

Thx, Harry

Comment: Found the solution here, last post by Support. 
Its because of multiple ASP server processes.
http://www.chartdir.com/forum/download_thread.php?bn=chartdir_general&pattern=&thread=1117550703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see here](http://www.chartdir.com/forum/download_thread.php?bn=chartdir_general&pattern=&thread=1117550703)

its not as difficult as it seems, you'll have to generate tempfiles, using an provided function as mentioned in the link. No big deal, but hard to find.

Greetings,

Harry